# Browser push notification by simply polling webserver

Tags: javascript, browser, notifications, push-notification, service-worker

I need to create browser push messages even **when page is not opened**. But I have some limitations because I am developing it in Salesforce. So when page is loaded I have javascript block that invokes backend method and gets response in callback function. And I found that teoretically I can use serviceWorker and it can communicate with page via postMessages and it can show notifications. I have already found an example for showing notification by clicking a button, but I still need to find way to use serviceWorker to communicate with page to get response from server. 
I have seen this guide about serviceWorker http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/service-worker/introduction/ but it is not very clear for me. I don't want to use any middleware as GCM, only JS on client side.
Please, give me some example code to do it.

Comment: Can you clarify your objective? You don't need a service worker if you just want to show a notification while your page is open.

Comment: @Marco I need to receive notification when page is closed. This is example https://storage-cdn.realtime.co/chrome-push/index.html

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to receive a notification when the page is closed without using the browser's push service.

Answer (score -2):

No....  Currently  there is only one way to show push notification to user when your website is closed by using service worker api.

The first way will show you the push notification only if your website is ope.
1)Ajax Polling 
   This is approach is called comet approach which used by the Facebook. In this approach you will poll to the server in the regular interval  (means you need to do ajax call to the server in regular interval ) to check whether user have any new notification to show. Please check the below code 
     $(document).ready(function () {
            setInterval(updateCount, 120000);
        });
var updateCount = function(){
         var url = example.com // give your own url

```
    $.ajax({

        url:ajaxURl,
        type: "POST",
        dataType:"json",
        error: function(error){
                console.log("Error occured in the ajax call while saving the endpoint",error);
             },
        success:function(data){
          console.log(data)
          if(data == new notifcation){
          //then show notification 
          }
        },
        timeout:60000
    });
```

};

```
This is simple approach to show the notification to the  user. 
Cons:- 1)It will trigger to many ajax call to the server which will eventually increase the load on the server.
        2)User have to be logged in to the system then only you can show notification to end user.
```

2) Service Worker Api
    In this approach you need to register the service worker api in the client browser. once the server worker api is register it will run in the background of the browser and wait for the push event.
    when the push event trigger the service worker api will fire the push notification even when your user is not logged in to your website.

```
Cons:- 1)the service worker api will only run in the certain browser 
       2)Your website should https for using the service worker api as they already mention in the article.
```

I hope i answered your query..

Comment: the first approach you have mentioned is totally wrong!! @ravi-gupta read question carefully "when page is not opened"